# Using PleaseWait.js loading screen with Vue-CLI

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, pleasewait

I need to use [PleaseWait.js](http://patgather.github.io/please-wait/) loader screen in my Webpack Vue-CLI project.

I searched for any Vue-friendly alternatives, but didn't find any suitable packages.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744020/how-to-implement-a-loding-screen-for-a-spa-written-in-vue-js), which is a demo of using PleaseWait.js with Vue, but it didn't work with Webpack, basically because of this error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   please_wait__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a
>   function"

I am looking for a way to make it work, or for any good alternatives.

Comment: Usually, your error shappens because you are impoprting the package wrongly, try `import * as pleaseWait from 'please-wait'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you would import it in your Vue CLI project:

1. Install `please-wait` as a dependency with this command:

   ```
   npm i -S please-wait
   ```
2. Create a single file component in `src/components/Loader.vue` with an empty template (`please-wait` already attaches its own HTML to the document):

   ```
   <template>
     <div v-once></div>
   </template>
   ```
3. In `Loader.vue`'s `<script>`, import `please-wait` and its CSS:

   ```
   import { pleaseWait } from 'please-wait'
   import 'please-wait/build/please-wait.css'
   ```
4. Also add a `prop` and a corresponding [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that will open the `please-wait` loader based on the `prop` value:

   ```
   export default {
     props: ['isLoading'],
     watch: {
       isLoading: {
         handler(isLoading) {
           if (isLoading) {
             this.open()
           } else {
             this.close()
           }
         },
         immediate: true,
       }
     },
   }
   ```
5. Also define the `open`/`close` methods used by the watcher:

   ```
   export default {
     methods: {
       open() {
         // Attaching a `pleaseWaitInstance` property (no need to declare)...
         if (!this.pleaseWaitInstance) {
           this.pleaseWaitInstance = pleaseWait({
             logo: 'https://pathgather.github.io/please-wait/assets/images/pathgather.png',
             backgroundColor: '#f46d3b',
             loadingHtml: '<p class="loading-message">A good day to you fine user!</p>'
           })
         }
       },
       close() {
         if (this.pleaseWaitInstance) {
           this.pleaseWaitInstance.finish()
           this.pleaseWaitInstance = null
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
6. In `Loader.vue`'s `<style>`, add CSS to make the loading message's text (created in the `open` method) appear white.

   ```
   .loading-message {
     color: white;
   }
   ```
7. In `src/App.vue`, import the `Loader` component from above, and add it to the template:

   ```
   <template>
     <div>
       <loading-screen :is-loading="isLoading"></loading-screen>
       ...
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   import Loader from "./components/Loader";
   ...

   export default {
     components: {
       'loading-screen': Loader
     },
     data() {
       return {
         isLoading: true
       }
     },
     mounted () {
       setTimeout(() => {
         this.isLoading = false
       }, 2000)
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/31vrlklljq?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FLoader.vue)

Answer (score 1):

[no export default](https://github.com/Pathgather/please-wait/blob/e920f1273d04617a0c32233fcf1e8affb4c384bc/build/please-wait.js#L290)

try

```
import {pleaseWait} from 'please-wait'
```

or

```
import * aspleaseWait from 'please-wait'
```